# How to keep actual file path accessible when the file has permalink key in the frontmatter?

Tags: url, path, non-ascii-characters, eleventy, slugify

Say a file is at `actual/path/`. Would having this `permalink` key in the frontmatter:

```
---
permalink: "a/different/path" 
---
```

making the link `https://example.com/actual/path` not working anymore? It seems yet, although the [documentation](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/permalinks/) doesn't seem to explicitly say so. In that case, is there a way to have `https://example.com/actual/path` still work? In my site the links are slugified, yet the paths are still untouched. In general I would like to keep both versions.